# Ubuntu 12.04 dropping LAN connection

Tags: networking, drivers, lan, interface

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 machine that has two Ethernet interfaces, both are static.

eth0 is sitting on a network like:
xxx.xxx.169.xxx with a 255.255.255.0 mask

It's static address is:
xxx.xxx.169.14

eth1 is the gateway to a sub network (also a dhcp server):
192.168.1.1

This network arrangement works fine when there is a direct lan connection from the xxx.xxx.169.14 managed switch.

I'm trying to introduce a client machine (Windows 7) that is also straddling both networks. To do this I've introduced a 4 port dumb switch between the xxx.xxx.169.14 managed switch and the two straddled computers.

The problem:

Windows doesn't have a problem (both machines are the exact same hardware), but Ubuntu get's intermittent connectivity to eventually no connectivity in a short period of time.

When I remove the dumb switch and direct connect the Ubuntu machine it's fine again.

I'm not sure what is going on here, can someone offer some assistance. My only thought (which I haven't tried) is maybe I need a better driver?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answered to the problem was changing out the dumb 5 port switch I was using.

Do not use this:

Cisco SF100D-05 if you are using a Linux machine with Realtek networking chipset.

https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11874911/unstable-link-sf100d-05